Can a person breathe in or out while transporting?
This is a follow-up to this question, which is instead about whether air is displaced by a transporting person's body.  ("What happens to the air surrounding a transport subject's origin point, or occupying the destination?")
As a Star Trek character is being transported, are they able to breathe in or out?  If so, does the inhaled/exhaled air come from or go to their old location, or their new location?

Does time even pass for the objects being transported?  I think establishing that would be a necessary precondition to even ask this question.

At least some episodes of NG have a containment field established around them (in some cases - the Hunted, for example, and Roga Danar both notices and is able to break out of it); it's not unreasonable to think a lesser version might apply to move gasses, although I'd think that could make for a loud displacement.  Several episodes seem to show some time passing while in transit (look at Barclay's experience), but, then, you also see people held in a kind of stasis at times, like Data with a discharging weapon after being captive. So... it doesn't seem terribly consistent.

I'm confident that I remember some character, possibly many, having made some utterance while being transported.  If true, this would imply that breathing is possible in transport.

Of course, a simple Handwavium answer would be 'It depends on the settings; they can control a lot of things from the panel.' (Watch out; that's a TvTropes link -- you can get lost for hours there, should you venture forth.)

There was the episode of TNG where Barclay was afraid to transport then during prolonged transport he saw something in the stream.  Then while in the stream he reached out and grabbed it (though this was an extra long transport time due to radiation) but it was still moving/seeing during transport.  During that it appeared he was breathing.

In The Wrath of Khan, Kirk and Saavik are shown having a conversation during an active transporter sequence. They must be breathing.

It has been to long since I have seen the shows, but with the exception of Barclay, I was under the impression they might START saying something while being transported, But FINISH it at the destination. They were NOT talking and exchanging information WHILE being transported. They MAY be talking while the shimmer is occurring, (I don't recall an instance) but while "enroute" AFAIR for the transported person, no time passes.

Just saw the Kirk and Saavik scene from Wrath of Khan, and she is talking in the arrival shimmer, and you can see others moving a bit. But unless anyone can point to other instances, I would consider this breaking cannon, and chalk it up as director's choice.

It depends on the era, and the transporter, but generally, yes.
People have been shown to have conversations whilst transporting, which would be difficult if they were unable to breathe mid-transport.
The air probably just goes along with them. We frequently see people try to stay separated when being transported (like Captain Pike telling someone to stand back when he was about to transport), or arrange themselves somewhat separately from a nearby group, which would suggest that it grabs a zone around the person, and the separation might be to stop any unwitting passers-by from being dragged into the transport, whilst also making it easier for the transporter operators to figure out who needs moving.
It's happened before, when Lt. Barclay held onto a second person during the materialisation sequence, resulting in them also getting materialised.
